# How to get rid of ssl.SSLCertVerificationError in Python 3.11.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, ibm-watson, libressl

I am currently working through the Python for Data Sciences course on IBM's [Cognitive Class](http://cognitiveclass.ai), and just started the lesson on APIs. The lesson wants me to use the RandomUser API, but whenever I try and access it with the following code:

```
from randomuser import RandomUser
r = RandomUser
some_list = r.generate_users(10)
```

I get the following error:
`ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1002)`

I am on a Macbook Pro with macOS Venture 13.3.1 and installed Python via Homebrew.

After some hours of googling and trying some things, I suspect it's a due to Python using the wrong openssl version on my Mac OS, but I am completely lost as to how to solve this problem.